# Run a script every day at a certain time automatically javascript

Tags: javascript, automation, timer

I have a visual studio code project with a main function main() in javascript, which I would like to run every day at 8am automatically without doing anything. Is there any way?
[main function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eQNDi.png)

I've seen things related to setInterval and so on but this doesn't run my project automatically.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24741530/in-javascript-how-can-i-have-a-function-run-at-a-specific-time/24741617#24741617

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: @Andy but I have to cick on run my function to execute that right? I want that it executes automatically every day at 8.00.